# How to rename a Google+ Page

Tags: google-plus

We recently purchased a hotel and are renaming it. Once I have ownership of the Google Plus page, how do I rename it? Or, do I have start from scratch?

Answer (score 6):

Simply go to the "About" section of your page, then click on the name in the header. (You should get a tooltip that says "Edit your name".) You may need to choose to "Manage" your page.

Then simply edit the name.

See also: [Getting started with Google+ pages](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1710691?ref_topic=3049734)

Comment: @Tom: I'm glad it was helpful. You should consider "accepting" this answer to act as a signpost for future readers. (More at our [Help Center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).)